# Are Media Queries Supported?

Tags: google-app-maker

I've added a media query for a page size < 800px, [like this,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcyDZ.png) and there is no change in size < 800px.

How is this type of responsiveness supposed to be done in App Maker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most media queries are supported for most widgets types. You can find expamles here:
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/

In your particular case, most likely you need to add '!important':

```
width: 100px !important;
```